# SharePoint 2010 Restore-SPSite problems

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, backup, restore

I have create SharePoint 2010 site collection backup through Power shell, by using the command

**Backup-SPSite "http://sitename:85" -path "C:\backup.bak" -Force**

and i am restoring this backup on same SharePoint 2010 server/same machine on different port by using the command

**Restore--SPSite "http://sitename:81" -path "C:\backup.bak" -Force**

it through this error

Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoin
t Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. Th
e backup file should be restored to a server with version '4.0.145.0' or later.
At line:1 char:15
+ Restore-SPSite <<<<  "http://sitename:81" -path "C:\backup.bak" -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite

***I am amazed. i create the backup and restore on same SharePoint server, then why it is asking different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.***

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue migrating SPF2010 to different server.

Sollution: database upgrade on source server.

How: Open Sharepoint PowerShell, and type **Upgrade-SPContentDatabase** command, hit R(maybe Y) when promt.

Cheers

Comment: Which server you are migrating from SP2010 to server?

Comment: If you are restoring the SharePoint 2010 portal on different sever and facing the same issue then you have to apply SharePoint 2010 SP1 on your SharePoint server and then restore portal backup. It will be hopefully restored.

Comment: Secondly if you don't want to install SharePoint 2010 SP1. Then you can save your entire sp site as template with content. Then upload this template to second server in solution gallery and create new site based on this template. This site will be same as you backup-ed from.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you applied SP1 to your SharePoint server. *Service Packs and Community Updates (CUs) may alter database schemes and backups made before applying such update may be unusable.* Microsoft mentions this at the description of [Restore-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx). See [Restore pre-SP1 backups to an SP1 farm (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh344827.aspx) and/or [Restore pre-SP1 backups to an SP1 farm (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh344831.aspx). The scope of your backup was a site collection which means that you would have to install a pre-SP1 SP server to be able to perform the restore there. Then you would upgrade the machine and backup the upgraded site collection. This backup would be restorable on your current server/farm. Painful, huh.

**A SharePoint backup should be restored on a SharePoint server/farm of the same version, including important updates.** Microsoft recommends doing a full farm backup after applying the SP1. I would make sure that backups are refreshed after every SP or CU.

You should not think about the backup as a long-term solution. As you see, not only it is not a cross-version archive but it may not survive even a service pack for the same version. SP Backup is a short-term safety like your UPS; long-term archive to retain your SP data accessible in the future is offered by other software vendors.

I run into similar trouble after applying CU 12/2011 and importing a site by [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx). The content deployment API is also sensitive to SP version changes; it is meant to replicate content from the staging to the production environment; not to archive/restore content.

--- Ferda